# How to match either a subset (preferred), or the whole line in a regex?

Tags: regex

I have a string that looks something like this:

```
"Element 1 | Element 2| Element 3: element 4"
```

I want to substring the portion of the source string that follows the colon (to the end of the source string), but if there is no colon, then I want to grab the whole string.

What I've tried so far are variations around this:

```
:.*|.*
:?.*
```

etc.

However, while they'll match if either the colon is present or not, they don't *prefer* the substring when the colon is found.

I've been playing with this on http://regexpal.com.

Ultimately, this will be used in a CMDB tool for matching CIs - so a general solution would be ideal, rather than language- or engine-specific.

Comment: @mikey how did you know it's JavaScript?

Comment: @MarounMaroun - I rolled the question back from that tag add

Comment: @MarounMaroun reference regexpal.com a javascript regular expression tester :)

Comment: @Mikey But that's relevant for other languages as well..

Comment: Ok, yeah but I just assumed it was javascript, but could also be PHP or whatever. Sorry

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
(:.*|[^:]*)$
```

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vA6mZ3/8)

Explanation:

> if there is no colon, then I want to grab the whole string

- This if condition can be specified using a negitive character class of colon

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
(?:^|:)[^:\n]*$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wK8mH9/1)